# jquery Ajax form not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a php file which imports the jquery.form.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createuser.js"></script>
```

createuser.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#UserButton").click(function() 
    {
        alert("Here1");
        var ID = $("#ID").val();
        $("#User_Form").ajaxForm
        ({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'createuser.php',
            data: {ID:ID},
            cache: false,
            error: function(data) 
            {
                bootbox.dialog
                ({
                    alert("error");
                });
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {

                if(data==0)
                {
                    alert("user created");

                }

            }
        }).submit();
    });

});
```

the createuser.js works till the first alert message i.e. Here1 but does not proceed further. the php script createuser.php works fine in isolation and returns 0. So there doesn't seem to be a problem with the createuser.php file.

Please let me know if i'm missing out on something.

thanks.

Comment: check this : http://jsfiddle.net/hRTcE/53/

Comment: Please also post your PHP script

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: No. Still troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the console you will see an error saying that `ajaxForm` is not a function.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
> ```

First you load a script which attempt to bind `ajaxForm` to the jQuery object. This fails.

Then you load jQuery.

You need to reverse the order you load those two scripts in.

---

It seems very strange to call `ajaxForm` in response to a click. Normally you would rant to call it in a `ready` handler so it would run when a regular submit button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an action in your code which seems like missing so your request will reach your createuser.php file but in response you will get 0 because there is no handler/action/function to handle that request.

Sample Code.
I hope it helps.

```
var ajax_data = {
        'action': 'test_get_meeting',
}

jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: ajax_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        jQuery("#spaces_section_meeting").html(response["data"]);
    },
    fail: function () {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that maybe your PHP script is probably returning no value since its returning false. You can `alert(data)` to see what values you are getting on success and failure.

```
data:{"ID":ID},
success: function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
            if(data!=1) 
            {
                alert("user created");

            }

        }
```

Also first include the jquery library right on top of the other libraries.

Comment: When i run the script in isolation it gives value 0 but when i call it through jquery nothing happens. Even alert(data) in success or failure doesn't get triggered. Is it that the ajaxform is not firing at all.

Comment: @dk007 did you take a look at the console if you are getting any errors?

Comment: Not returning any error. I have another project and this script works absolutely fine there so I'm quite clueless that why isn't it working now

Comment: @dk007 try `data:{"ID":ID}`  and also put the `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` above `jquery.form.js`

Comment: 1.11.1 **is** newer than 1.5

Answer (score -1):

change code in data in ajax to:

```
data: 'ID='+ID,
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.

Comment: No. Look at [the documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object). It says that `data` is *An **object** containing extra data that should be submitted along with the form*. It doesn't say that a string is valid there.